# <br clear="all"> or similar in CKEditor - Trying to do a clean break

Tags: ckeditor, formatting

So here is the deal, I am trying to have a clean break between images and text and am unable to use  in CKEditor. There is [this plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/brclear), but its not available via the CKeditor congfig, and I am not trying to maintain another extension to keep it running every time I update CiviCRM. Is there another way to get the same result using the stock CKEditor that is bundled with CiviCRM? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope I've understood your issue correctly.  A workaround here is to use the editor to insert an image in the place where you wish it to appear.  Right click on the image to bring up image properties.  Select the advanced tag and in style, enter the following CSS  "margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" (without the quotes). That should centralise the image horizontally on the page.  If you want more margin space on the page, you can use the Hspace or Vspace in the Image Info tab in image properties.  Hope that helps.

Comment: No, I want a clear break. Image on left, text wrap, then clear break, new image on left, text wrap, clear break, repeat. Imagine mosaico blocks with left aligned images but texts wraps and then new block starts clean.

Comment: Within CKEditor and the Styles button, there is a "Special Container" which basically is a <div> tag.  Using the source code you can delete/change the background colour and border where required.  In the Container/<div> tag, you can insert both images (aligned as needed) and text where required.  I think this could acheive what you require.
Alternatively, why not just use Mosaico and its blocks, as it seems you have it installed?

Comment: This is for an event page, not for an email. headshots and bios. I tried what you suggested, it still does not work as needed. The only thing that has ever worked for me is <br clear="all">